# Publishing and consuming both debug and release libraries to Maven for Android

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin

Given that now you can get Gradle to generate both `mylib-debug.aar` and `mylib-release.aar` in `build\outputs\aar` by issuing the `./gradle build` for a libary, when I try to publish both types to Maven I get an error unless I classify them.

```
publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.mydomain'
            artifactId 'mylib'
            version '0.1'
            artifact bundleRelease { classifier 'release' }
            artifact bundleDebug { classifier 'debug' }
            ...
            //code for source and pom
            ...
        }
    }
```

Issuing `./gradle publishToMavenLocal` I end up with these files in `~/.m2/repository`

```
+--com
  +--mydomain
    +--mylib
      +--0.1
         + mylib-0.1.pom
           mylib-0.1-debug.aar
           mylib-0.1-release.aar
           mylib-0.1-sources.jar
           maven-metadata-local.xml
```

Now when I try to import this using

```
dependencies {
    debugImplementation  group: 'com.mydomain', name:  'mylib', version: '0.1', configuration: 'debug'
    releaseImplementation  group: 'com.mydomain', name:  'mylib', version: '0.1', configuration: 'release'
```

it doesn't work.  I have tried other combinations, but have found nothing that works.

Comment: Show your android block. Are you coding into debug build and release build blocks for allowing signing configuration changes to affect your dependencies, or are you using flavors? How are you attempting to toggle the dependency? You could also hackily do inline groovy to check build type and change the string but that is not necessary

Comment: The debug configuration has different dependencies, does more logging and is more "debugging" friendly. The key is that I can't get the gradle dependencies to resolve as soon as I use classifier on the aar